# jQuery ajax remember variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I need to keep track of prevoius selection made

This code runs after each ajax success

```
var region = $("#regionDropDown :selected").html();
var newRegion;

if ($('#regionDropDown').find("option:selected[value!='all']").length) {
    var region = newRegion;
    var newRegion = "-Region: " + $("#regionDropDown :selected").html();
}​
```

But this wont work, I get undefined on region.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign region = newRegion which means they are now both undefined and your data is lost.
You don't need that line (`var region = newRegion;`)

Comment: So how can I make region contain the content of newReion? I need to update the content for each updated selection :P

Comment: `var newRegion = region; var region = ...` and then your old data is still in `newRegion`. Maybe it's a good idea to change the variable's name :)

Comment: Hmm.. isn´t that what I´m doing?     var region = newRegion; var newRegion = ...

Comment: if `newRegion` is empty, and you do a `var region = newRegion`, they will both be empty. What `var region = newRegion` does is create a new variable called `region` (overwriting the old one) and assign whatever's in `newRegion` to that. Understand this and you'll be on your way to your solution.